# email email existence verification endpoint protection

Tags: authentication, security

We'd like to implement a login/registration flow that asks for the email address of the user frist, checks if this email address is already registered and based on the results, redirects the user either to the login page or into the registering process (both are regular implementations of oAuth using Auth0).

A lot of app/services/websites are using a similar authentication flow and I'm wondering how these are protecting their systems agains missusage like brute-force checking for email addresses to figure out if this email is existing and registered with the service.
I've not been able to find best-practices specific for this particular case.

The flow is running on our mobile app only (iOS & Android). We already considered some options:

- using a certificate to sign the request - but then comes the question how to keep this certificate secure.
- rate limiting litterally has it's limits as well as
- ip blocking or
- device fingerprinting.

So we did not find a solution yet that we feel confident to use. Any advice on how to protect such an email existence verification endpoint against missusage?

Comment: Instead of designing such a system yourself you should take a look at [OAuth](https://oauth.net/). There are many OAuth/OIDC implementations and servers available like for example [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)

Comment: @XaverKapeller We're using OAuth and Auth0 for the authentication. So we're not talking about the authentication method itself, we're using established standards here. We're just looking for a reasonable way to secure the mentioned email existence verification endpoint to route the user to either the login or registering process.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Then this is a decision you should make based on your requirements. There is no single correct answer. There are a lot of Services out there that do not or only barely mitigate against user enumeration attacks. For services like this, knowing if a user has an account, might only be of very limited use to an attacker. Most that do protect endpoints like this just use Rate Limiting. In most cases there is no other option for protecting an endpoint like this, because it has to be an unauthenticated endpoint since it is used during the user registration process.